# Android infinite URL load

Tags: java, android, url, timeout

I'm building an application that in the splash screen, loads data from a file via a URL online. This app is currently working, published, and getting great reviews :)

I have, however, noticed that on certain devices (namely the HTC Desire) when I instantiate a URL, lets say like:

```
url = new URL("https://www.blah.com/blah.txt");
```

the URL will just hang there, and the splash screen will load infinitely. I've tried putting this into its own thread and throwing a timeout when this happens, but it seems that its locking even that up, as the timeout never gets caught from the parent thread's wait function.

Now, as I've said, this seems to only be for the HTC Desire, as most devices are using my app without a hitch. And its not happening on every HTC Desire with the app. The devices that are having issues seems to occur sporadically. Sometimes the app will function fine, sometimes it will infinitely load. When its happens, it happens on both WiFi and 3G. If the user kills the app while its infinitely hung, then reopens, it fixes the issue and loads fine.

I'm out of ideas here...anyone have any? The only thing I can think is trying a different constructer, maybe like:

```
url = new URL("https", "www.blah.com", 443, "/blah.txt");
```

but I'm not too network-savvy, and have trouble determining other ports such to use. The site I'm using is an "https" site.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Are they running through a proxy of some sort? What is your sample size? You have seen this occur on 1 HTC Desire phone or 20?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the connection timeout with `setConnectTimeout()` on the `URLConnection` object. This will allow you to catch the `SocketTimeoutException` and either retry or do something else.